# converting json in dataframe to separate columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have implemented an emotion analysing using lstm. I am doing the prediction part. I have created a dataframe with my results. In the dataframe, I am having a column having a json file. I want to break this json file and create columns for each labels in the dataframe. I am posting my codes and my results as well as what I want as result. Can you please tell me where I need to modify and what do I need to do please.

here are my codes:

```
       with open('emotion.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(new_data, f)

import re
def remove_bracket(text):
    x = re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", text)[:-1]
    return x
selection1 = new_data['selection1']
#creating empty list to be able to create a dataframe
names = []
dates = []
commentss = []
labels = []
hotelname = []
sentimentanalysis = []

for item in selection1:
    name = item['name'].split('(')[0].strip()#Removing all brackets that are present in the hotel name
    hotelname.append(name)
    #print ('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ', name)
    Date = item['reviews']
    for d in Date:
        names.append(name)
        #convert date from 'january 12, 2020' to 2020-01-02
        date = pd.to_datetime(d['date']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        #adding date to the empty list dates[]
        dates.append(date)
        #print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ', date)
    CommentID = item['reviews']
    for com in CommentID:
        comment = com['review']
        lcomment = comment.lower()  # converting all to lowercase
        result = re.sub(r'\d+', '', lcomment)  # remove numbers
        results = (result.translate(
        str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))).strip()  # remove punctuations and white spaces
        comments = remove_stopwords(results)
        commentss.append(comment)
        print('>>>>>>',comments)

    #add the words in comments that are already present in the keys of dictionary
        encoded_samples = [[word2id[word] for word in comments if word in word2id.keys()]]


    # Padding
        encoded_samples = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(encoded_samples, maxlen=max_words)

     # Make predictions
        label_probs, attentions = model_with_attentions.predict(encoded_samples)
        label_probs = {id2label[_id]: prob for (label, _id), prob in zip(label2id.items(), label_probs[0])}
        labels.append(label_probs)
       #Get word attentions using attenion vector
        print(label_probs)
        #label_probs is a dictionary and k is the argument passed to lambda function which is the key dictionary label_probs
        maxlabel = (max(label_probs, key=lambda k: label_probs[k]))
        print(maxlabel)

        sentiment = []
        if maxlabel == "disgust":
            sentiment.append("negative")
        elif maxlabel == "happy":
            sentiment.append("positive")
        elif maxlabel == "trust":
                sentiment.append("positive")
        elif maxlabel == "joy":
                sentiment.append("positive")
        elif maxlabel == "anger":
                sentiment.append("negative")
        elif maxlabel == "sadness":
                sentiment.append("negative")

        #sentimentanalysis.append(sentiment)

#creating dataframe
dataframe={'name': names,'date': dates, 'comment': commentss, 'classification': labels, 'sentiment': sentimentanalysis}
table = pd.DataFrame(dataframe, columns=['name', 'date', 'comment', 'classification', 'sentiment'])
print(table)
```

My results:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/StDsb.png
```

and I want my results to be like this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdS5W.png
```

as you can see in the second image that is the result i want, I have eliminated the [''] in the sentiment column.. how can I modify my codes to do this?

And what do I need to modify to be able to have my expected results guys?
Please help me please.

Comment: your images are both identical

Comment: Post your data as text, create a minimal and reproducible example @Nedisha

Comment: Yes I have just corrected it sir. sorry

Comment: If you include an example emotion.json file this would be much easier for me to run and therefore answer.

Comment: This is my emotion.json file :https://jsonblob.com/8252d15a-6935-11ea-9705-7125a8893ce4

Answer (score 0):

I stripped down your code to just fix the last few lines. This addresses your specific question.

Since your code won't run I created dummy data based on your images.

I included lots of comments. Ideally, you shouldn't make a mess of things earlier on in your code. If you follow my example in all of your code you won't end up with a mess like this in the future. The trick is to print out everything at each step of the way to see that it is indeed what you think it is. In many cases you have lists of dictionaries instead of dictionaries of lists, or you have lists of lists instead of lists.

```
import pandas as pd

labels = [{'trust': 0.01, 
'disgust': 0.001,
'anger': 0.33,
'sadness': 0.02,
'happy': 0.004,
'joy': 0.63},
{'trust': 0.01, 
'disgust': 0.001,
'anger': 0.33,
'sadness': 0.02,
'happy': 0.004,
'joy': 0.63}]

names = ['radisson', 'blah']
dates = ['2020-12-1', '2020-12-2']
comments = ['radisson', 'blah']
sentimentanalysis = [['positive'],['negative']]


#creating data frame incorrectly
dataframe={'name': names,'date': dates, 'comment': comments, 'classification': labels, 'sentiment': sentimentanalysis}


print(dataframe)
table = pd.DataFrame(dataframe, columns=['name', 'date', 'comment', 'classification', 'sentiment'])

print(table)

# to fix this mess:
# always add comments
# 
dataframe_fixed={'name': names,'date': dates, 'comment': comments}
# print at each step (or use pycharm to debug)
print(dataframe_fixed)
# create an array for each key
for key, value in labels[0].items():
    dataframe_fixed[key] = []

print(dataframe_fixed)
# fill with values
for label in labels:
    for key, value in label.items():
        dataframe_fixed[key].append(value)

#

print(dataframe_fixed)

# fix sentimentanalysis:
# create empty array
sa_fixed = []
print(sentimentanalysis)
# remove extra list
for s in sentimentanalysis:
    print(s[0])
    sa_fixed.append(s[0])

print(sa_fixed)

# add to dataframe:
dataframe_fixed['sentiment'] = sa_fixed

print(dataframe_fixed)

table_fixed = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_fixed, columns=['name', 'date', 'comment', 'trust',
'disgust','anger', 'sadness','happy','joy', 'sentiment'])

print(table_fixed)

# really, you shouldn't make such a mess in the first place.
```